# Jquery, how to use a method once and only once on the inital page load?

Tags: jquery

I have some code that fades in the container div of the home page of my site and a picture frame around it, but I don't want it to ever display that effect again, even on subsequent page reloads, or even when the home page link is clicked. How would I go about this? Here is the code I currently have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquerys.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img.frame").hide(0,function(){
  $("div.container").hide(0,function(){
  $("img.frame").fadeIn(1000);
  $("div.container").fadeIn(1000);
   });
  });
 });
</script>
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by using cookies.

Just write a cookie with a boolean value which should point to the fact that some request isn't the first one.

Finally, just put an "if" and eval if some cookie is true/false.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do in JavaScript but I guess it could never work because it gets reset every time the page loads right?, Thank You!

Comment: No, cookies will live even if page is reloaded. There're 3 chances to get a cookie removed: user deleted private data, cookie expiration or user removed the web browser (or it's computer went to the toilet! ;) ).

Answer (score 2):

Could you create a cookie on the first time loading, and check if that cookie is set?  If its set then don't call that code.